# In a Diffie-Hellman key exchange Find this key and compute the shared secret key k

Tags: public-key, diffie-hellman, keys, key-exchange

Hi I struggling to find the answer of my schhol exam, can anyone help me .

**In a Diffie-Hellman key exchange the multiplicative group of integers modulo
p is used with the parameters p = 59, g = 3 mod 59. The public keys A = 28 and
B = 36 are exchanged. One of the private keys is relatively small. Find this key
and compute the shared secret key k.**

I know how to find the shared secret key but i do not know how to find private key that is small.

Comment: Are you aware of how the public keys are derived from the private keys? Combine this with the exercise's hint that one of the private keys is 'relatively small' - can you then think of how to figure out said private key?

Comment: Per [policy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), homework questions must come with description of what has been tried/where one is stuck. Thus I'll only give some clarification of that homework. What it names "public keys" is what's exchanged between the communicating parties; and what it names "private key" is what [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#Cryptographic_explanation) names "secret integer".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138666/discussion-between-yen-and-fgrieu).

Comment: I'm looking for the same problem. Can anyone please help me how to find it. Thank you

Comment: @radha gudala: please read this the content of [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138666/discussion-between-yen-and-fgrieu). You should be able to talk, too. If you want to ping me, include "@ fgrieu" at the end of the message, without the quotes and with the space moved BEFORE the @ sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hearing that the private key is relatively small means that probably you could compute it via brute-force, meaning just trying values until you find the answer.

So, you have your generator $g=3$ and you can just start trying small exponents. Eventually, you would find that $g^9 \equiv 36 \mod 59$.

Therefore, you now know that B's private key is $b=9$. From that, you just continue the protocol as if you were B to find eventually the shared key to be 5.

Comment: Yes. Additionally, it's inexpensive to go from one private key tried to the next: all there is to do is multiply by $g$ modulo $p$. The computations go: $g^1\bmod p=3\bmod59=3$, $g^2\bmod p=3×3\bmod59=9$, $g^3\bmod p=9×3\bmod59=27$, $g^4\bmod p=27×3\bmod59=22$, $g^5\bmod p=22×3\bmod59=7$, $g^6\bmod p=7×3\bmod59=21$, $g^7\bmod p=21×3\bmod59=4$, $g^8\bmod p=4×3\bmod59=12$, $g^9\bmod p=12×3\bmod59=36$, matching B (we would have stopped if we matched A).

Answer (score 1):

We should be able to brute-force it easily.

```
i = 3
iteration = 1

while True:
    if i % 59 == 28:
        print(f'28: {iteration}')
        break
    if i % 59 == 36:
        print(f'36: {iteration}')
        break
    i *= 3
    iteration += 1
```

FYI: 9 was printed out.

Comment: @fgrieu should be good now (:

Comment: It now works. A possible improvement is to prevent `i` from growing unnecessarily large. Replacing the current `i *= 3` by `i = i*3 % 59` and removing the two earlier `% 59` fixes that. Perhaps I would also start at `i = 1` with `iteration = 0`, with the benefit that $g$ and $p$ now appear only at a single place.